# How to send data from a website to a processor via a serial port?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, arduino, serial-port

I am building a simple, physical alarm clock that gets its hours from a React app . I have already created a very simple app, and a program for the processor in C, using a program called Hercules. I now want to be able to send the data (hours) from the website to the processor (ATMEGA 328P processor (Arduino)) via a serial port (using a USB cable).

The first thing I need to do is send a number (e.g. 67).

So, what happens after I hit submit on a form in my React app until it gets to the processor? What's the easiest way to make this happen and what should I learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an API that you can call from your React app. This API would then interface with your Arduino. There seem to be a bunch of packages that allow you to interface with your Adruino from Node: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=arduino. I also found a tutorial here: https://desertbot.io/blog/control-arduino-with-nodejs. This uses ExpressJS to serve your API. Overall, this is a pretty broad topic so I hope this helped you in the right direction.